# Has any commercial airliner ever flown inverted?

Tags: commercial-aviation, accidents, emergency-procedures, commercial-operations, accident-statistics

Has any commercial airliner ever flown inverted, either intentionally (extremely unlikely) or during an upset?

Comment: (I know that the linked question does not ask the same question, but the first answer is a commercial airliner so it still answers your question)

Comment: There was a flight a good while ago that had (IIRC) and engine explosion that crippled most of the controls, and inverted was the only way the airplane would fly -- they flipped upright again just before crashing, with some survivors.

Comment: In 2018, an employee out of SeaTac stole a Q400 [and did a number of aerobatic maneuvers before crashing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2cI1iaSXpjs) **warning, possibly disturbing/language**.

Answer (score 2):

[FedEx Flight 705](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Federal_Express_Flight_705), a DC-10-30 cargo plane, flew at 140 degrees (40 deg off being level inverted) after an attempted hijacking. The FO, Jim Tucker, flew the plane inverted to attempt to throw the would-be hijacker off-balance. The hi-jacker was dead-legging, and was worried that he was about to be sacked by FedEx.